# How to find logarithmic function between known linear set of data and known logarithmic set of data.

Tags: functions, logarithms

There is a 'black box' system that provides a three sets of data, between which there is a correlation, e.g.:

1. **X** = {1.00, 0.95, 0.90, 0.85, 0.80} - **linear set**. Values are equidistantly distributed between **1.00** and **0.80**.
2. **Y** = {1.00, 0.99111397, 0.96492686, 0.92281021, 0.80} - **logarithmic set**. Values are calculated from the 1st set by using of so called **Logarithmic Factor = 2**. The distribution of values in this set reminds some logarithmic function, but marginal values remained the same, i.e. **1.00** and **0.80**.
3. **Z** = {1.00, 0.99821644, 0.98582030, 0.95294412, 0.80} - **logarithmic set** again, just values are calculated from the 1st set by using of **Logarithmic Factor = 3**. The distribution of values in this set reminds some logarithmic function, but marginal values remained the same, i.e. **1.00** and **0.80**.

See the following picture with [distribution of values from above mentioned linear and logarithmic sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DIQz.png).

I need to mathematically describe the behavior of mentioned **black box** system and to extend it's functionality in the mathematic model.
I was trying to find/calculate function Y=f(2,X) and Z=f(3,X), but till now without any success.
First I tried to calculate function by application of suggestions in this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472747/convert-linear-scale-to-logarithmic

Then I tried to use linear approximation, but this didn't bring good results too.
To reach the same marginal values I have played with norming of results from some found function, but without success again.

I also tried this online equation finder, where it is possible to select, whether final function
shall be polynomial, logarithmic, exponential, etc. https://www.dcode.fr/function-equation-finder .
But if any function was found, it was applicable either between data from sets X and Y (but then not between X and Z), or between data sets X and Z (but then not between X and Y).

I am not sure what logarithmic factor is in this case. Maybe it has nothing to do with logarithms. At least marginal values are the same in all three sets.

So, how to find a logarithmic kind of function between known linear set of data and known logarithmic set of data?

Comment: Why do you think these have a "logarithmic" relationship?

Comment: Because this 'black box' system explicitly requests to set value named 'Logarithmic Scale Factor' so that it could provide logarithmic set of data from linear set of data.

Comment: Logarithms in general do not fix any point, much less two. The most likely possibility is that it is a linear translation of a logarithmic function, Something of the form $$f(x) = \log_b(x - a) + c$$ with the base $b$ acting as your "logarithmic factor". $a$ and $c$ are determined by the equations $f(1) = 1, f\left(\frac 45\right) = \frac 45$, though their values would depend on $b$ as well. But there are infinitely many other functional forms possible, that could still be considered "logarithmic". This is a crapshoot. You can only hope you get lucky.

Comment: I finally had the time to check the form above. It doesn't work (even allowing $b$ to be something other than $2$ or $3$). The value of $b$ that matches $0.99111397$ doesn't match the other two interior values. (and it took a $b$ on the order of $1.1E14$ to match the first value). Maybe they are raising a logarithm to some fractional power instead.

Comment: I was trying to find a base of logarithm as follows:
if Logarighm with base B of 0.95 equals to 0.99111397,
then B raised to the power of 0.99111397 equals 0.95

Comment: That will not work. As I've already said, no straight logarithm fixes *any* value (correction: if the base $< 1$, then it will fix one value, but not two). But you want a function that fixes two values: $1$ and $0.8$. It is **not** going to be a function of the form $f(x) = \log_b x$. Whatever else it does other than just taking a logarithm is going to change the value at the other points as well, not just at $1$ and $0.8$. So trying to use those values directly to find the logarithm base is wrong.

Comment: Now I am thinking about difference between numbers. In this linear dataset X the difference between numbers is 0.05. In logarithmic dataset the difference between numbers logarithmically decreases/increases (depending on point of view) and probably these differences are somehow related to the powers of 2 (in case of dataset Y) or powers of 3 (in case of dataset Z).

Comment: Just additional comment to Your previous comment - I am trying to find some function that will match only to these 3 interior values. It seems like I can ignore marginal values 1 and 0.8, because they are remaining unchanged regardless of what Logarithmic Scale Factor was selected.